# Logback-classic conflict with SLF4J through different dependencies

Tags: logstash, slf4j, logback-classic, logstash-logback-encoder

I have an internal library that was upgrade to use `logstash` which has a mandatory dependency to `logback`, hence `logback-classic` (**which has its own slf4j appender internally of its packages, which means I can't exclude any library here**).

When I try to use this dependency as a jar over any other legacy module (all of them are using `slf4j-log4j12`) I do get the log dependency hell message:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/asdf/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/asdf/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.26/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.26.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

**but the problem itself is that *I can't* just exclude logback-classic, since it is mandatory for logstash, and I can't migrate my applications to use logback, since they are configured with the log4j.xml**

Is there a way to force slf4j to use *the application appender* instead of the one that comes from the logback library, OR, any other idea to make just a given *package* to use an appender, and the rest, use other?